# Azure Cosmos DB Mongodb $t and $v

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I got 2 Azure Cosmos DB's which runs in MongoDb. The first one was created by someone else and second one was created by me.

If I query my database, my structure gets very weird with a $t and $v property.

My structure:

[image]

Structure of the other DB (like it should be):
[image]

My backend does work properly with both, but I want to add Azure Search and I can't do this with my structure. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would you please tell me what language of MongoDB API did you send the two of the json data into the Document DB ?

Answer (score 1):

(If someone can make this a comment instead of an answer, it would be appreciated)

I'm getting the same thing. It looks like Microsoft gave an answer here as to why it happens: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/e0ffdbcd-0b43-4cd5-9d21-1a95ce0279dd?category=azuredocumentdb

> The incorrect format is a result of intermixing the Cosmos DB: MongoDB API with the Cosmos DB: DocumentDB API.

It's not very clear to me though why those two are intermixed since MongoDb maintains the MongoDB API NuGet.

Comment: Microsoft needs to provide Extremely Clear Guidance about what is going on and what the consequences of Azure Setting Have on my long term data storage.   I just want to shove JSON in Cosmos and Get the exact same JSON back out of Cosmos for both Cosmos and Mongo clients.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because one of your Cosmos DB MOngoDB API accoutn is older than the other - older one uses JSON schema (used by SQL API as well), while newer uses more versatile (and MongoDB compliant) BSON schema. You just need to request the conversion of the account to a new schema by emailing askcosmosmongoapi@microsoft.com